# Why does the second build screen only display "more..." in original Civilization?

Tags: civilization

When I click of "change" in a city in original Civilization and then "more...", I have the following screen :

[image: more more]

There should be the list of city improvement.  Is that a known bug?

Is there a work around?

This is version 475.01.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Have you tried pressing either/both of the "More..." prompts on the blank screen?  I kind of remember seeing this, but it's been a long time.

Comment: @agent86 clicking on the first "More..." does nothing.  The second one close the gray square (same as clicking outside of the gray square).

Comment: Whoa, *this* is what the original Civilization looked like? Civ II came leaps and bounds!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went back in my save game and checked at each turn, it is caused by the number of element in the second screen being too high (about 32).

Answer (score 1):

Because the problem is caused by having too many choices of improvements to build in the city, the work-around is to build wonders in cities that have not yet run into this problem.

The most effective wonder to build is Hoover Dam on the same continent, because it substitutes for Power Plant, Hydro Plant, and Nuclear Plant.  It thus reduces the improvement choices by 3 or 4.

As shown in the original post, the wonder that is most likely to trigger this bug is Apollo Program, because it enables SS Structural, SS Component, and SS Module.  It thus increases the improvement choices by a net of 2.